# If it is possible to put several values in "case" in c#

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Is it possible to put several values inside the case?

```
Switch(colorCode)
        {
          case (colorCode > 1 && colorCode < 5)
             color = red;
          case (colorCode > 6 && colorCode < 9)
             color = green;
          case (colorCode > 10 && colorCode < 15)
             color = blue;
        }
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, what do you mean? Case can have a block. You assign one value - if you do multiple assignments the last one wins. It is totalyl unclear what you try to argue.

Comment: Looks like you want a set of if/else-if statements rather than a switch statement.

Comment: I have one input value, it can be from 000 to 1000. I didn’t want to use "If"  because it is very large and not readable.

Comment: Switch expressions must be constant at compile time, so you can’t do that

Comment: @stuartd Can you advise what should I use in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `when` keyword:

```
    int colorCode = 4;
    string color = "";
    switch(colorCode)
    {
        case int i when (i > 0 && i <= 3):
            color = "red";
            break;
        case int i when (i > 3 && i <= 6):
            color = "green";
            break;
        case int i when (i > 6 && i <= 9):
                color = "blue";
            break;
    }
```

ps: don't forget to break your case statement

Answer (score 1):

Contra the other answers, this is indeed possible in C#7:

```
Color color;

switch(n)
{
  case int m when m >= 1 && m <= 3:
    color = Color.red; break;
  case int m when m >= 4 && m <= 6:
    color = Color.blue; break;
  case int m when m >= 7 && m <= 9:
    color = Color.green; break;
  default:
    color = Color.other; break;
}
```

I don't necessarily recommend abusing the type pattern switch in this way, but strictly speaking it can be done.

A clearer way would just be to use an if / else if / else block:

```
if(n > = 1 && n <= 3)
{
  color = Color.red;
}
else if(n >= 4 && n <= 6)
{
  color = Color.blue;
}
else if (n >= 7 && n <= 9)
{
  color = Color.green;
}
else
{
  color = Color.other;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes and no

it is possible to jump from one case statement to another,
but it is not possible to set ranges (for C# up to version 5).

the adjusted code would look like this:

```
    switch(colorCode)
    {
      case 1: 
      case 2: 
      case 3: 
         color = red;
         break;
      case 4: 
      case 5: 
      case 6: 
         color = green;
         break;
      case 7: 
      case 8: 
      case 9: 
         color = blue;
         break;

    }
```

(I assume you want to include the border values, like 1,3, 4, 6 etc, according to your comparisson using < > you would not include these values)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is a very wordy way of doing this:

```
color = colorCode == 8
  ? blue
  : colorCode == 5
    ? green
    : colorCode == 2
      ? red
      : color ;
```

I'm not sure if what you showed in your question would actually do what you want. Assuming colorCode is an integer, > 1 && < 3 is simply == 2.

Comment: It was a simple example. The real value is from 001 to 010, 011 to 020 and etc.

Comment: Nested ternarys are evil.